# Autocomplete textview not showing any data

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting a place's name from the Places API. The problem is that my autocomplete TextView is not showing me any data for testing. I am adding a `OK1`, but it's not showing anything when I add something without a sync task it shows data but when I enter second character in text field it crashes the application.

```
destiantion=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text);
destiantion.setThreshold(1);
resultList1=new ArrayList<String>();
destiantion.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
  {

    String place=s.toString();
    final String url="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"+"address="+place+"&sensor=true";
    try
    {
      //destiantion.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(StartJourney.this, R.layout.auto_complete_items));
      //destiantion=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    class innerClass extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object>
    {

      @Override
      protected Object doInBackground(String... params)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Network netwrok=new Network();
        try {
          String response=netwrok.sendData(url,"TEST");



        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        resultList1.add("OK1");
        destiantion.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(StartJourney.this, R.layout.auto_complete_items));
      }
    }
    new innerClass().execute();
  }
```

Adapter class is

```
private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
  private ArrayList<String> resultList;

  public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId);
      System.out.println("ENTER IN AUTO COMPLETE");
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return resultList.size();

  }

  @Override
  public String getItem(int index) {
      return resultList.get(index);
  }

  @Override
  public Filter getFilter() {
    System.out.println("ENTER IN FILTER");
      Filter filter = new Filter() {
          @Override
          protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
              FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
              if (constraint != null) {
                  // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                  resultList =getResultList();
                  // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                  filterResults.values = resultList;
                  filterResults.count = resultList.size();
              }
              return filterResults;
          }

          @Override
          protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            System.out.println(results.count);
              if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                  notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
              else {
                  notifyDataSetInvalidated();
              }
          }
      };
      return filter;
  }
}
```

Comment: post your relavant log cat and te line tat causes the error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException iam getting on second letter it shows list and then crashes the application

Comment: Wats the line throwing null pointer?